# Exclude rows on "shuf" command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a csv with 100 rows, i want shuffle all rows skipping the first 2, but i dont find how exclude the first 2 lines

Now it is like this:

```
shuf words.txt > shuffled_words.txt
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Pipe the output of `tail` to the command.

Comment: `seq 1 5 | sed 1,2d | shuf`

Answer (score 3):

Or something like this:

```
( head -n 2 words.txt ; tail -n +2 words.txt|shuf ) > shuffled_words.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great:

( read -r first; read -r second; printf '%s\n' "$first" "$second"; shuf ) <words.txt >shuffled_words.txt

Answer (score 2):

The shell lets you easily combine text and file manipulation commands using pipes.

```sh
sed 1,2d words.txt | shuf >shuffled_words.txt
```

There are many ways to skin this cat; `tail -n +2 words.txt` or `awk 'FNR>2' words.txt` are also common and idiomatic ways to remove the first two lines.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but i think i dont explain myself:

I have a csv with the next rows:

Row 1 header
row 2 header2
text1
text2
text3

I want the shuffle output something like this:

Row 1 header
row 2 header2
text2
text1
text3

I want the first row to be exclude from shuffle but not from output

Comment: `( read -r first; read -r second; printf '%s\n' "$first" "$second"; shuf ) <words.txt >shuffled_words.txt`